# subtraction in linux shell if

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In linux bash shell, how to subtract a variable from another in `if`? I've tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
start=0
end=1
if [ end - start -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "right"
fi
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you specifically mentioned bash, use its arithmetic support:

```
#!/bin/bash
start=0
end=1
if ((end - start == 1)); then
    echo "right"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something something like as shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
start=0
end=1
if [ `expr $end - $start` -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "right"
fi
```

Comment: Or `if expr $end - $start = 1 > /dev/null; then ...`

Comment: Only very old, non-POSIX shells require `expr` for math. Use `$(( $end - $start ))` instead.